# php variable gets null at the end of the script?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem that I really can't figure out. basically I'm working on a blog and I have a variable from a cookie that returns a post id. the problem is that at the end of the script, when I enter an if(isset) statement, the variable seems to be null and I can't understand the reason behind it. it won't add anything to the database and it won't redirect to the post id. here's the script:

```
<?php
//display the post
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `post_id`='". $post_id. "';") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
    $currentrow = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $currentrow['title']. "<br>". $currentrow['text'];
}
else
{
    echo "that post does not exist.";
}
?>
</div>

<div id="comments">
<br>
<h3>Comments</h3>
<br>
<?php
//display the comments
$comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` JOIN `posts` ON(posts.post_id=comments.post_id) JOIN `users` ON(users.user_id=comments.user_id) WHERE posts.post_id=". "'". $_GET['post_id']. "'". ";")or die(mysql_error());;
while($currentRow = mysql_fetch_array($comments))
{
    echo $currentRow['ctext']. "<br>";
    echo "posted by <a href='/templates/profile.php?name=". $currentRow['name']. "'>". $currentRow['name']. "</a> at ". $currentRow['cdate']. " -- ". $currentRow['ctime']. "<br><br>";
}
?>
</div>

<Form Name ="submitform" Method ="POST" ACTION = "post.php">
<div id="commentbox">
<textarea name="textarea1" rows="10" cols="30">
<?php
echo $post_id;
?>
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submitcomment" value="Submit"><br>
</div>
</Form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitcomment']))
{
    $comment = $_POST['textarea1'];
    $user_id = $_COOKIE['userid'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(`ctext`, `cdate`, `ctime`, `user_id`, `post_id`) VALUES('$comment', 'CURDATE()', 'CURTIME()', '$user_id', '$post_id')") or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location: /post.php?post_id='. $post_id);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see, I'm echoing that variable in the textarea1 just before the if statement and it returns the correct value, but at the end it's null. thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up **SQL injection**: you have a **serious security issue** with the INSERT part. Using `$_POST['textarea1'];` without at least sanitizing with mysql_real_escape is dangerous! Google for Little Bobby Tables to see what I mean... On a second thought the SELECT is troublesome too. Not to mention: mysql_* is deprecated. Either mysqli, or better: PDO would be good.

Comment: where are you setting the COOKIE value..?

Comment: I know I have security issues, I will fix them in the last part.

Comment: I'm setting the cookie value in the main blog page, it's working fine. it's just that the variable seems NULL in the if statement. in the rest of the script it's visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not at the end, it is actually a different execution of the file.

When you submit your form your file gets called again and there is no post_id parameter so $_GET['post_id'] returns an empty value in the assignment at the beginning of the file.

Try adding a hidden field to your form, or changing the action to

```
post.php?post_id=<?php $_GET['post_id'] ?>
```

so you don't lose the value after the form submission.

Comment: thank you, this worked. and I understand the reasoning behind it, which is more important.